# Add custom authorization rule spring security

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt, authorization

I faced problem implementing following authorization rule using Spring Security:
User resource can be modified only by owner or user with admin role. By modify I mean triggering API endpoint of PUT method and such URL - some_path/user/{userId}

Needed to mention conditions:

- app applies microservices, so my service don't have access to user database
- input data for authorization is JWT in Authorization header. JWT contains "sub" value that is user id of whom were issued token and "roles" array of his roles

How I can implement such functionality in most Spring Security way? Did I really need to implement my own AuthorizationManager?

Comment: What is the Spring Security version you're planning to use? Based on that you'll need to implement OAuth2 either by using spring-security-oauth2 or spring-authorization-server.

Comment: Version 6.1.5, latest on current date. 
Yes, I understand my authorization flow is quite similar to OAuth2, but do you really think OAuth2 will solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest option is to use "method security" and SpEL (`@EnableMethodSecurity` or `@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity` depending on your application being a servlet or a reactive app).

I'll consider in the following that your entity has an `owner` property containing user subject (or whatever you configured to use as `name` in the authentication converter). Something like:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String owner;
}
```

with

```java
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {}
```

You can then implement such a controller:

```java
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @PutMapping(path = "/my-entities/{entity-id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('admin') || #myEntity.owner == authentication.name")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> updateMyEntity(@PathVariable("entity-id") MyEntity myEntity, @RequestBody @Valid MyEntityeUpdateDto dto) {
        ...
        return ResponseEntity.accepted().build();
    }
}
```

In the expression above:

- `#myEntity` refers to the `myEntity` argument of the decorated method (an entity auto-magically retrieved by a `@Repository` using the ID passed as `@PathVariable`)
- `authentication` is "magic" variable containing the `Authentication` instance in the security context

I intensively use this kind of rule in [this project](https://github.com/ch4mpy/quiz) as can be seen for instance in [that controller](https://github.com/ch4mpy/quiz/blob/main/api/quiz-api/src/main/java/com/c4soft/quiz/web/QuizController.java).

Answer (score 0):

Here's roughly what you can do. You can implement spring-authorization-sever for OAuth2 to have custom jwt token & custom jwtAuthenticationConverter with GrantedAuthorities having the roles as per your requirement. Once you read the JWT token for authorities, use `@PreAuthorize` annotation to restrict the access to the said endpoint.